# How to get checkbox data in textarea and textarea data in scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I want checkbox data in textarea and get textarea data in parragraph by using scope. i want to get checkbox data in textarea and edit data and get textarea data in {{newer}}.

i have added checkbox value in textarea using checkbox scopes and similarly textarea scope in parragraph

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<input ng-model="er1" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'10th / '" ng-false-value="">10th
<input ng-model="er2" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'12th / '" ng-false-value="">12th
<input ng-model="er3" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'B.Ed / '" ng-false-value="">bed

<textarea ng-model="newer">{{er1}}{{er2}}{{er3}}</textarea>

<p>{{newer}}</p>

</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller(function($scope) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-change` directive:

```
<input ng-model="er1" type="checkbox" ng-change="updateTextArea()"
       ng-true-value="'10th / '" ng-false-value="">10th
<input ng-model="er2" type="checkbox" ng-change="updateTextArea()"
       ng-true-value="'12th / '" ng-false-value="">12th
<input ng-model="er3" type="checkbox"  ng-change="updateTextArea()"
       ng-true-value="'B.Ed / '" ng-false-value="">bed

<textarea ng-model="newer">{{er1}}{{er2}}{{er3}}</textarea>

<p>{{newer}}</p>
```

```
app.controller(function($scope) {
    $scope.updateTextArea = function() {
        $scope.newer = $scope.er1 + $scope.er2 + $scope.er3;
    };
});
```